# If $u$ is algebraic over $F$, then $u+a$ is algebraic over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

Assume that $u$ is algebraic over the field $F$, and that $a\in F$. Show that $u + a$ is
algebraic over $F$, find its irreducible polynomial over $F$ and show that deg($u +
a,F$) = deg($u,F$).

I made some observations:

$u$ is algebraic over $F \Rightarrow$ $f(u)=0$ for some nonzero $f(x)\in F[x]$. Let $n$=deg($u,F$). Then $u^n+a_{n-1}u^{n-1}+...+a_0=0$.

Now I tried to manipulate with $(u+a)^m+b_{m-1}(u+a)^{m-1}+...+b_0$. Since $F$ is a filed, we can use binomial theorem. Goal is to show $n=m$ and to find structure of this polynomial. I'm not sure if I can approach with some kind of $g(u)=f(u+a)$. I'm a little bit confused about how to proceed with all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing $x$ with $x-a$ in $f$ yields the polynomial $g(x)=f(x-a)\in F[x]$ and we have
$$
g(u+a) = f(u+a-a) = f(u) = 0.
$$

Comment: Isn't it part of the problem to show that $f(x-a)\in F[x]$ ? If we take it for granted, yes the problem is trivialized.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that: $x$ and $a$ are elements of $F[x]$ and $f$ is built from addition and multiplication with other elements in $F[x]$, which is a ring after all.